# Why is my SVG with position absolute not exactly at the edge?

Tags: css, svg, responsive

Whenever I try to position a scaled SVG with `position: absolute;`, and use 0 as the positioning parameter (i.e. `top:0;`) the svg does not seem to connect seamlessly.

Especialy when zooming or when creating a responsive layout, this seems to occure.

Consider the following example:

an item with SVG's as rounded corners:

```
<div class="item">
        <svg class="corner top-left" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;" xml:space="preserve">

          <path class="st0" d="M10,0H0v10c0-2.7-0.1-6.5,1.7-8.3C3.5-0.1,7.2,0,10,0z"/>
          <line class="st1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="9.9" y2="9.9"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="corner top-right" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;" xml:space="preserve">

          <path class="st0" d="M10,0H0v10c0-2.7-0.1-6.5,1.7-8.3C3.5-0.1,7.2,0,10,0z"/>
          <line class="st1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="9.9" y2="9.9"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="corner bottom-left" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
           viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;" xml:space="preserve">

        <path class="st0" d="M10,0H0v10c0-2.7-0.1-6.5,1.7-8.3C3.5-0.1,7.2,0,10,0z"/>
        <line class="st1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="9.9" y2="9.9"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="corner bottom-right" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
           viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="enable-background:new 0 0 10 10;" xml:space="preserve">

        <path class="st0" d="M10,0H0v10c0-2.7-0.1-6.5,1.7-8.3C3.5-0.1,7.2,0,10,0z"/>
        <line class="st1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="9.9" y2="9.9"/>
        </svg>
</div>
```

The corners are positioned with `position: absolute;` and rotated in css

```
.corner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
}
.top-left {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.bottom-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.bottom-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Now, depending on your screen resolution, you'll see the corners won't all fit seamlessly to the edge. Also when zooming in/out to the website oyu'll see a gap between the SVG and the edge of the element.

A dirty fix is to just offset the element minus 1 pixel in the direction it is positioned. However, the gap seems to be smaller than 1 pixel, thus breaking the design of the element when offsetting 1 pixel. Also, the gap does not appear all the time, only at certain pixel breakpoints.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pafke/eamn3u54/)**

To clarify, I want to prevent these lines from happening:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make rounded edges for a box? Maybe you should use the `border-radius` CSS property instead!

Comment: @IrvinLim No this is just an example. It could be any kind of SVG.

Comment: @RobertLongson While this greatly reduces the smoothness of the corner, it does not appear to fix the issue. The gaps still apear. `geometricPrecision ` Doesn't fix the issue either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a particularly elegant solution to this problem.  It affects Firefox mostly, because I believe Chrome/Webkit tends to snap elements to pixel boundaries, whereas Firefox doesn't.

One solution is to alter your paths so that they draw slightly outside the SVG and then set the `<svg>` to `overflow="visible"`.

```
<svg class="corner top-left" ...snip... viewBox="0 0 10 10" overflow="visible">
    <path class="st0" d="M10,0 V-2H-2V10H0c0-2.7-0.1-6.5,1.7-8.3C3.5-0.1,7.2,0,10,0z"/>
 </svg>
```

Here, for this top-left SVG, I have created a two-unit "porch" up and to the left.  Then if overflow is set to visible, the path will overdraw the little red lines caused by anti-aliasing/rounding.

[Here's a demo fiddle with (only) the top left SVGs modified.](https://jsfiddle.net/eamn3u54/1/)

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider this an elegant sollution? Seems fine to me. As far as Chrome/Webkit goes, they actualy tend to give me the most problems, especialy when zooming out/in, but your sollution appears to be covering this. Thank you.

Comment: I consider it inelegant because it relies on an element overflowing and drawing outside its container.  So, if you had other content hard against the edge of your div it could get over-written by the SVGs.  It's a little bit of a kludge.